# how to highlight some specific text with color background inside input field in - angular

Tags: angular

for example, a user enters some number of character in the input field and I want to highlight only the "hello" character in the input field (highlight like Grammarly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can try

1. [Make the content of a div editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)
2. On every [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), check the [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)
3. For every piece of text that you want to highlight, wrap it in a span having a class with background-color as the desired highlight color.

Comment: yeah thanks, this looks perfect I think this should work